# CSS not loaded in view when sent in email

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, materialize

I'm working with laravel5 and using materialize
whene I send a view in email the css is not loaded 
I tried to make my css files inlined but this don't work

here is an example of what I'm sending :

head tag :

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<title>my web site</title>
<!-- CSS  -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/materialize.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
```

page content :

```
<header id="top" class="nav-down">
<nav class="nav-wrapper yellow darken-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        welcome all
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you provide example of what you're sending?

Comment: Email is not like other web-based stuff. You can't just include the CSS, or for that matter, expect inline CSS to work as you would expect. I suggest you look into "how to write HTML emails" via Google. You'll realise you'll need to go back to the late 90s and make it with `<table>`and such clever "hacks".

Comment: junkfoodjunkie is right. I recommend using this: https://putsmail.com/inliner

Comment: godblessstrawberry I edit my question so you can see what I'm sending

Answer (score 1):

you need to inline styles for **each element** to ensure css delivered. you can use this tool to do that automatically https://putsmail.com/inliner

Comment: I'll try this now

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using css-inline-style for EVERY HTML-TAG you should consider that some Email-Apps and Web-Interfaces BLOCK html. So you should always attach a "second" email containing only text.

Here is an Example how to do so: http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/100130-html-email-multi

And you can forget stuff like:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Here is why: Outlook.com for example only renders the `<body>` part inside it's own DOM - not in an iframe as older versions did. (They of course check and verify the code before showing it), so your meta-Tags would be lost.
And passing the encoding is not not to be done by your html but by the email itself.

Your Email-Header should contain entries like this:

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

Hope this helps.